# Why go http client puts transfer-encoding=chunked header while processing POST

Tags: http, go

I make POST request like so:

```
// ...pack non-zero buf
req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bufio.NewReader(buf))
req.Header.Add("X-Uid", "12345")
req.Header.Add("Content-Length", strconv.Itoa(buf.Len()))

client := http.Client{}
resp, err := client.Do(req)
```

I expect that no "Transfer-Encoding" header would be passed, but I see in server logs that "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" header is passed.

Comment: And why is that a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a `bufio.Reader` to the http request. Since you can't determine the length of a `bufio.Reader`, the http package overrides the `Content-Length` to ensure the request is valid.

If you have the content buffered, and you know the length, there's no reason to wrap it in a `bufio.Reader`, just pass the buffer in directly. If you don't have the content buffered already, allow it to use chunked encoding which shouldn't make any functional difference in the request.